# Is there a way to find the download URL for apps from the Mac App Store?

Tags: software-recommendation, mac-appstore

I've found an open source script [ipatool](https://github.com/majd/ipatool), but that only seems to work for iOS apps.

Is there a way to find the URL to the app files for an app in the Mac App Store?

Comment: What OS are you using to find and download or are you wide open to any requirements for this software recommendation? The mas cli might be adaptable for your needs - https://github.com/mas-cli/mas but I’m not certain there’s a URL that’s stable as I haven’t used the tool in a while or looked deeply at the code.

Comment: Isn't share button in the upper right corner in the Mac App Store provide the URL? Or you want to do this in the command line?